# How to add music to Quake1?

Tags: quake

I am using Quakespasm (version 0.85.9) - 64 bit on Windows and it works very well.

I found a free music pack named [`quake1_music_diabolipak.pk3`](http://quakeone.com/forums/quake-mod-releases/finished-works/7802-diabolipak-alt-music-replacement-pack-quake.html), which I unpacked into the folder `C:\Programs\quakespasm-0.85.9_win64\ID1\sound\cdtracks` which now contains `track002.ogg .. track011.ogg`.

But it doesn't work. The game won't play any music. I also tried with putting the `pk3` file directly into `ID1` folder (without extracting) but it also doesn't work.

Any idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They need to be in `{game}/{mod}/music` so move them to `{game}/id1/music`

ensure that the cvar `bgm_extmusic` is set to `1` and that you are not using the command line option `-noextmusic`

Typing `music <filename>` at the console will play a specific music file.

Source:
http://quakespasm.sourceforge.net/music.htm

(note that in the document above they cite the track names as track02.ogg (2-column numbers with a single leading 0). This might mean your file will not load automatically, I don't know.)